# Interpolation and extrapolation in Gaussian Process Regression

Tags: gaussian-process

I'm looking for some references that have studied the behaviour of Gaussian process regression for the different settings of interpolation, and extrapolation.

I've found answers(e.g. [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31095360/extrapolation-using-gaussian-processes-regression-or-kriging)) that states when extrapolating far enough from a data point, the GP just regresses to the mean function. However, I would like to have a formal reference, and if possible exploring in more detail this issue.

Answer (score 5):

Well, the regression to the mean of a GP is "well-known" but actually not always true.

Let $m:D\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be the (prior) mean function and $K:D\times D\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be the covariance function of a GP. After observing data $(x_i)$ your posterior mean function will be:
$$ \hat{m}(x)= m(x) + \sum_i \alpha_i K(x_i,x)$$ for suitable $\alpha_i$. (see [Rasmussen/Williams](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW2.pdf) Equation (2.27) ).

Since the $\alpha_i$ are constant, the behaviour far enough from data points is entirely determined by $m$ and $K$. Let us assume for simplicity that $m=0$, i.e. zero-mean GP. Then "regression to the mean" means small values of $K(x_i,x)$ for $x$ far away from the data $x_i$. This is true for many popular kernels in GP regression, most notably for the Gaussian kernel ($exp(-x^2)$). But this is not the only possible choice. Not all kernels have $K(x_i,x)\rightarrow 0$ for large $x$. Counterexamples are kernels such as the exponential kernel $\exp(<x,y>)$ linear kernels or even the constant kernel $K(x,y)=c$.

If you are interested in interpolation and approximation errors, machine learning literature is probably not the right place for you. Look at books such as [Wendland](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521131014) or the lecture notes by [Schaback](http://num.math.uni-goettingen.de/schaback/teaching/Appverf_II.pdf).